# Configuring jackd (JACK daemon) with ALSA

Tags: daemon, jack, usb-audio

I'm trying to wrap my head around ALSA config files and jackd, but I'm not getting anywhere, other than crashing my machine.

The microphone is a USB type and specified in ALSA arecord as `-D plughw:1,0`.

Is there a way to use jackd to duplicate that microphone source?

Ideally, I want it to appear as a new device, so that `arecord -l` lists it separately, and I can open one or the other independently.

Comment: might be helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples